# Centering a button spanning muliple columns in a QGridLayout

Tags: qt, button, qt4, alignment, grid-layout

I have a button that spans two columns in a Grid Layout. The button is about half the width of its cell and I want it to be centered.

```
gridLayout->addWidget(btn3, 2, 6, 1, 2);
```

aligns the button the left of the cell, which I would assume to be the default. I tried

```
gridLayout->addWidget(btn3, 2, 6, 1, 2, Qt::AlignHCenter);
```

and the button disappears. Where did my button go and why is it not in the center of my layout cell?

I am using QT opensoure in Linux (ubuntu 10.04).

A bit of context:

```
gridLayout->addWidget(btn1, 2, 3);
gridLayout->addWidget(btn2, 2, 5);
gridLayout->addWidget(btn3, 2, 6, 1, 2);
gridLayout->addWidget(btn4, 2, 8);
gridLayout->addWidget(btn5, 2, 10);
```

I want btn3 to be in the center of its two-column-spanning cell, but when I attempt to pass Qt:AlignCenter as the 6th argument in the addWidget() method, btn3 disappears.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a ColumnSpan of 2, your button is probably under some other Widget of your gridLayout. Try changing your code to:

```
gridLayout->addWidget(btn3, 2, 6, 1, 1, Qt::AlignCenter);
```

It works fine to me.

Comment: I've edited the above question by adding some context. I intentionally want the cell btn3 is in to span two columns.

Comment: Can you add more code? I created a new layout were I added the buttons in the way you specify and the button b3 appears and is centered in my layout.